# How to send large amount of data to soap web service as input parameter?

Tags: php, soap, progress-4gl

When I send input parameters from PHP I do it like this:

```
$data = [
        'param1' => "value"
    ];
```

In my `.p` procedure I define that parameter as

```
DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER param1 AS CHARACTER FORMAT "x(50)".
```

And later on I can use that `param1` anywhere in my code.

But how to format data in PHP for temporary table as input parameter?

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE inputTable
FIELD field1    LIKE sometable.field1
FIELD field2    LIKE  sometable.field2.

DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER TABLE FOR inputTable.

FOR EACH inputTable:
//store data into progres database
END.
```

Is it possible to send a table as input parameter to SOAP web service and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the solution is very simple.

I had only to reverse the whole story.

So in procedure code stays like before

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE inputTable
FIELD field1    LIKE sometable.field1
FIELD field2    LIKE  sometable.field2.

DEFINE INPUT PARAMETER TABLE FOR inputTable.

FOR EACH inputTable:
//store data into progres database
END.
```

And in php i send array like this one

```
$data = [
        'inputTable' => $dataFromDB->toArray()
    ];
```

Only thing to worry about is that in variable `$data` you have values for columns `field1`, `field2` etc. Tried it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

1. Send the data to your WSA via JSON.
2. Change "parm1" to a LONGCHAR
3. In your program, have the TT defined, and then use the READ-JSON() method to get the data into the TT. In your case you'd substitute parm1 for the file name, and change "file" to "longchar".

See the ABL Reference guide under READ-JSON() for this code example and related docs:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cSourceType AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cReadMode AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cFile AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lRetOK AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE hDSet AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
CREATE DATASET hDSet.
ASSIGN
    cSourceType = "file"
    cFile = "dset.json"
    cReadMode = "empty".

lRetOK = hDSet:READ-JSON(cSourceType, cFile, cReadMode).
```

Comment: Can you provide some code with dummy JSON, parsing it into progress object and storing it into database?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the Progress docs for details on moving JSON data around the way you're asking for.